# Calculating sequence product

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I need your help calculating the limit of:

$((n+a_{1})(n+a_{2})...(n+a_{p}))^{1/p}-n$

I've tried to multiply by the conjugate but the expression isn't friendly. Also I've tried to decompose the expression like a sum of logarithms but isn't work well.

Could you give me a hand??

Thanks!!

Comment: The limit as $\ldots$? As $n \to \infty$?

Comment: Yes @BrianTung. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hints: Write that as  $$n[\,(1+a_{1}/n)(1+a_{2}/n)\cdots (1+a_{p}/n)\,]^{1/p} - n.$$ Recall $(1+h)^{1/p} = 1+h/p + O(h^2)$ as $h\to 0.$